# making a gravity effect inside html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the position of a circle inside a canvas using random x and y when hitting the space bar but i am stuck to figure out how I should implement a gravity effect so when the circle change it's position it come back down to the ground in a smoothy way 
my jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/efcnM/5/

how can i modify my update function to succeed my gravity effect

```
function update() {
    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
        var spacebarHit = e.which == 32 || e.keyCode == 32 ? true : false;
        if (spacebarHit) {
             Bluecircle.y -=1;// RandomPos;
             Draw();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `while(Bluecircle.y>0){Bluecircle.y = u*t+(1/2)*(-9.81)*t*t; t++}`

Comment: Time, surely. Look at the fiddle I've posted in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the real-world equations of motion?

```
if (spacebarHit) {
             var oldPos = Bluecircle.y;
             var u = 50;
             var g = 9.81;
             var t = 0;
             var handle = setInterval(function () {
                 t++;
                 Bluecircle.y = oldPos-(((u)*t-(g/2)*t*t));
                 console.log(Bluecircle.y);
                 if (Bluecircle.y>oldPos) {
                     Bluecircle.y = oldPos;
                     clearInterval(handle);
                 }
             }, 100);

             Draw();
         }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/efcnM/11/)

Comment: can you explain the equation u used ?

Comment: this is a great answer i just modified this line : ` if (Bluecircle.y>oldPos) {
                     Bluecircle.y = oldPos;` to ` if (Bluecircle.y>oldPos) {
                     Bluecircle.y = ch;` so the ball go back to the ground and don't stuck in middle air

Comment: @Sora I've used the equation `s=ut+(1/2)at^2`(where *s* is the distance, *u* is the initial speed and *a* is the acceleration(I've used *g* which is the *acceleration due to gravity*)). This is the second [equation of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion). And yes, `Bluecircle = ch` might be slightly better(I used `oldPos` since the ball was on the ground to start with) you'll have to tinker with it to get precisely what you want. You can also modify the t increment and the setInterval period to get a smoother transition. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/efcnM/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonian integration:

```
function mainLoop(dt) {
    circle.acc.x = 0
    circle.acc.y = 9.81 // positive is down

    circle.vel.x += circle.acc.x * t
    circle.vel.y += circle.acc.y * t

    circle.pos.x += circle.vel.x * t
    circle.pos.y += circle.vel.y * t

    // check if the bottom of the screen has been hit, and
    // clamp circle.poa to he within the world

    // do bounces by flipping the sign of components of circle.vel
}

function jump() {
    circle.vy = -20; // or something
}
```